# Open new tab without leave focus on previous tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to open a new tab on click but i want to previous tab always active, child tab not active by default

My code is-

```
             <a onclick="window.open(URL); self.focus();>Click</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

This behaviour is up to the browser and can't be controlled by Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can write code onload of the new window that gives focus back to the opener:

```
window.opener.focus();
```

notice that window.open opens a new window not a new tab, `target=_blank` opens a new tab (optionally according to browser settings)

Comment: make sure you call it onload of the whole body, and maybe settimeout of 100 ms

Comment: I just tried it, I'd say Chrome is smart, it really does ignore the whole focus line

Comment: What if the new window is not one of yours? What if OP wants to load www.google.com?